# Improper data testing in python

Tags: python, testing, time

I am trying to test user input, but it only seems to work the first time through. If I give the correct data the first time, it works, but if I originally give the wrong data and then use the correct data after being re-prompted it never recognizes it as correct. Any idea why it works the first time but not any time after that? Here is the code,

```
testDate = open("Sales.txt")




def DateTest(Date, Position):

    firstTry = True
    validSyntax = False
    Done = False
    while Done == False:

        while validSyntax == False:

            if firstTry == True:
                print "debug 2"
                try:
                    Date = Date.strip().split(',')
                    Year = int(Date[0])
                    Month = int(Date[1])
                    Day = int(Date[2])
                    Date = (Year, Month, Day)
                except:
                    print "That is invalid input."
                    firstTry = False
                else:
                    validSyntax = True
                    print "ok got it"

            elif firstTry == False:
                NewDate = raw_input("Please input the desired %s date in the form YYYY,MM,DD: " % Position)
                try :
                    NewDate = startDate.strip().split(',')
                    Year = int(NewDate[0])
                    Month = int(NewDate[1])
                    Day = int(NewDate[2])
                    NewDate = (Year, Month, Day)
                except:
                    print "That is invalid input."
                else:
                    validSyntax = True
                    print" ok got it"

        if validSyntax == True:
            for line in testDate:
                line = line.strip().split(',')
                yearTest = int(line[0])
                monthTest = int(line[1])
                dayTest = int(line[2])
                dateTest = (yearTest, monthTest, dayTest)
                if Year == yearTest:
                    if Month == monthTest:
                        if Day == dayTest:
                            Done = True
                            print "success"
```

Comment: Your code is *really* repetitive. Try making functions to wrap repetitive blocks. That way, you can pinpoint errors much faster.

Comment: You should use a loop instead of repeating the same code.

Comment: Im putting the right input the first time and it is coming with an error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a loop to check a date with datetime in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11075810/using-a-loop-to-check-a-date-with-datetime-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

To address why it isnt working currently: you never set `startDate`, and so the attempt to `strip().split()` will not work:

```
            NewDate = raw_input("Please input the desired %s date in the form YYYY,MM,DD: " % Position)
            try :
                NewDate = startDate.strip().split(',') // startDate isnt set
```

you can try

```
           startDate = raw_input("Please input the desired %s date in the form YYYY,MM,DD: " % Position)
            try :
                NewDate = startDate.strip().split(',')
```

I agree with the commenters that you could take a stab at refactoring your code to consolidate repetitive sections.

Comment: @tabchas In addition to @akf's comment you might consider using Python's [`time`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#module-time) module to parse your string into a `time` object that you can use for checking. It will throw a `ValueError` exception that you can catch if the time format is incorrect.

Comment: I have fixed most of my code, but am coming up with a problem. As you can see I have a for loop inside my program, the problem is that for loop only runs once. If I have to re-run the for loop do you know how  I can get it to run a second time?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a refactored version:

```
import time

DATE_FORMAT = '%Y,%m,%d'

def parse_date(date_str, fmt=DATE_FORMAT):
    try:
        return time.strptime(date_str.strip(), fmt)
    except ValueError:
        return None

def get_date(adj='', fmt=DATE_FORMAT, prompt='Please enter the {}date (like {}): '):
    prompt = time.strftime(prompt.format(adj.strip()+' ' if adj.strip() else '', fmt))
    # repeat until a valid date is entered
    while True:
        inp = raw_input(prompt)
        res = parse_date(inp, fmt)
        if res is None:
            print('Invalid input')
        else:
            return res

def get_test_date(date, adj='', fmt=DATE_FORMAT):
    return parse_date(date, fmt) or get_date(adj, fmt)

def find_date_in_file(fname, date_str='', adj=''):
    test_date = get_test_date(date_str, adj)
    with open(fname) as inf:
        for line in inf:
            if test_date == parse_date(line):
                print('Found!')
                return test_date

def main():
    find_date_in_file('Sales.txt', '2012,01,05', 'closing')

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```